# VueJS data binding for multiple same components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have parent component  and

Parent.vue:

```
<Child v-for="item in list" :key="item.id" />
```

I need an approach idea how to bind data between parent and child components.
Example:
The child component has a form that I want to bind with a parent component to do a validation inside the parent component, e.g. show a button inside in parent button only if each child component form is validated

Thank you

Comment: You will need to emit events from child to the parent

Comment: The parent component communicates with the child using a prop. The child component communicates with the parent using emit. If you have something that does not fit into this concepts, then there are other ways. But you don't provide any details and code examples...